# Trouble creating a webhook using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Has anyone had any luck creating a webhook to receive notifications about changes to O365 calendar's events? I've been successful with the Outlook Notifications REST API, but trying the same with the new Microsoft Graph API has been a bumpy ride.

I've acquired an app-only token for https://graph.microsoft.com and I can generally use both v1.0- and beta-endpoint services just fine. However, when I try to create a new subscription (POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions), I get this rather blurry error:

```
401 Unauthorized: {
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Invalid security token.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c5a64878-e643-41be-b863-a598e05f38a4",
      "date": "2015-11-28T17:59:24"
    }
  }
}
```

I've given the following application permissions to my app: *Microsoft Graph -  Read all users' full profiles, Read directory data*, and *Read calendars in all mailboxes*. According to the documentation *Calendars.Read* permission is required.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong or might it be that the create subscription service is unable to properly handle app-only token's?

EDIT:

The decoded token is:

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY",
 kid: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/58108de9-edf3-####-b20b-817520334d13/",
 iat: 1448814967,
 nbf: 1448814967,
 exp: 1448818867,
 appid: "5e80f22f-ff14-####-962a-2a9362a6057c",
 appidacr: "2",
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/58108de9-edf3-####-b20b-817520334d13/",
 oid: "87b9064d-3dc7-####-9071-7a61b5b57840",
 roles: [
  "Calendars.Read",
  "Directory.Read.All",
  "User.Read.All"
 ],
 sub: "87b9064d-3dc7-####-9071-7a61b5b57840",
 tid: "58108de9-edf3-####-b20b-817520334d13",
 ver: "1.0"
}.
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a decoded app only access token please? JWT.calebb.net is great for decoding tokens

Comment: The access token looks fine. We'll need to get back to you on whether the subscription service supports app only tokens, or whether something else is going on here. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Subscriptions are on a per user basis right now, therefore they cannot be created using an app-only token. Thank you for the feedback we will look into adding support for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, got it. You might in the meantime improve the error message - right now it is totally misleading.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347541/are-app-only-tokens-already-available-for-microsoft-graph-api-webhooks

Microsoft Graph API now does support Application permissions.