# Are app-only tokens already available for Microsoft Graph API webhooks?

Tags: office365, webhooks, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I'm trying to retrieve information via a webhook, regarding User's OneDrives on a Tenant, using an app-only token, and the Microsoft Graph API.

The problem I'm having is that the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) keeps returning me an undefined error in an **500** response, that gives me little information, when creating a new **subscription**:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "16546770-c3b0-4d9f-8a9c-1a79fb17ffcd",
            "date": "2016-09-06T10:15:04"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the information I'm sending via POST to *https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions*:

```
{
  "changeType":"updated",
  "notificationURL":"https://{URL to notification page}",
  "resource":"/drives/{User's OneDrive drive ID}/root",
  "expirationDateTime":"2016-10-20T11:00:00"
}
```

In [previously answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975044/trouble-creating-a-webhook-using-the-microsoft-graph-api), there was a reference (answer by [Yina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3661913/yina)) about subscriptions being on a per user basis, and not being able to be created by an app-only token.

My questions are, if this is currently still true, and if using an app-only token with full access I can subscribe to User's OneDrive webhooks.

**PS:** I am retrieving User's OneDrives with this token, without an issue, just haven't been able to subscribe to changes in the root item of the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, the WebHooks of Microsoft Graph is still only support for the delegate token.

It means that we are not able to create the subscription using the app-only token. If you want the Microsoft Graph support this feature, you may submit the feedback from link [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com).

Answer (score 1):

Webhooks have supported Application Tokens for a while now.
Reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks

Here's a sample project that demonstrates using App-only tokens.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-apponlytoken-webhooks-sample