# Access token validation failure when creating Microsoft Graph webhook using the "Web API on-behalf-of flow"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, webhooks, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What I am trying to do is to use the "Web API on-behalf-of flow" scenario Microsoft described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations) to create a web hook.

So I started with the [Microsoft github example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) and made sure that I can successfully get the users profile via the Graph API.

Then I modified the code where it gets the users profile to create the web hook, so the code looks like this:

```
// Authentication and get the access token on behalf of a WPF desktop app.
// This part is unmodified from the sample project except for readability.

const string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.com";
const string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
const string clientId = "my_client_id";
const string clientSecret = "my_client_secret";
const string assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

var user = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,new DbTokenCache(user));
var assertion = ((BootstrapContext) ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext).Token;
var userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null
    ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value
    : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;

var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,new ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret),new UserAssertion(assertion,assertionType,userName));

var accessToken = result.AccessToken;


// After getting the access token on behalf of the desktop WPF app,
// subscribes to get notifications when the user receives an email.
// This is the part that I put in.

var subscription = new Subscription
{
    Resource = "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = "https://mycompany.com/subscription/listen",
    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4230, 0)
};

const string subscriptionsEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, subscriptionsEndpoint);

var contentString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscription, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
request.Content = new StringContent(contentString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Parse the JSON response.
    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    subscription = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Subscription>(stringResult);
}
```

The error I get from the response is:

```
{
 "error":
 {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError":
    {
      "request-id": "f64537e7-6663-49e1-8256-6e054b5a3fc2",
      "date": "2017-03-27T02:36:04"
    }
  }
}
```

The webhook creation code was taken straight from the [ASP.NET webhook github sample project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample), which, I have also made sure that I can run successfully.

The same access token code works with the original user profile reading code:

```
// Call the Graph API and retrieve the user's profile.

const string requestUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/mycompany.com/me?api-version=2013-11-08";
request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);
```

So I want to find out:

1. Is creating a webhook via the graph API using the on-behalf-of flow even supported? Not sure if [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975044) is what I'm looking for here.
2. If it is supported, what am I missing here?
3. If it is not supported, is there an alternative to achieve it? E.g. is there anything from the existing Office 365 API that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > "message": "Access token validation failure.",

The error means you got incorrect access token for the resource . According to your code ,you get the access token for resource :https://graph.windows.net( Azure AD Graph API) , But then you used that access token to access Microsoft Graph API(https://graph.microsoft.com) ,so access token validation failed .

Comment: Spot on Nan Yu! I changed my resource to "https://graph.microsoft.com" when getting the access token and now I'm able to receive the validation token sent to "https://mycompany.com/subscription/listen". After returning the token to the Graph API, I am now getting `code: ExtensionError, message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]` from the web hook response. I have already given my multi-tenant web application the delegate permission to "Read user mail" from "Microsoft Graph" API. Do you know what else I'm missing here?

Comment: Please firstly check the 'scp' claim in access token includes the correct permission .

Comment: You are right Nan Yu, the scp claim only has "User.Read". After a bit of fiddling, I found out that in the Azure AD app registration portal, I had to not only give my multi-tenant web app the delegate permission to "read user mail" but also had to use the "Grant Permissions" button at the top of the "Required permissions" panel to "grant the permissions for Multi-tenant web app for all accounts in current directory". Only after this, the scp claim in my access token can become "Mail.Read User.Read".

Comment: @Leon Zhou ,glad to hear that you have solved the problem

Comment: Two separate APIs with the same name from MS it's really hard. I've spend HOURS to find a glue :( And there is no offline (service like) app auth library (is it?). I've just use HttpClient + manual cache for this